# Getting Longest Word - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a function that returns the longest string in the given array. If the array is empty, it should return an empty string (""). If the array contains no strings; it should return an empty string.

```
function longestWord(arr) {
 var filtered = arr.filter(function(el) { return typeof el == 'number' });
  if (filtered.length > 0) {
    return Math.min.apply(Math, filtered);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

var output = longestWord([3, 'word', 5, 'up', 3, 1]);
console.log(output); // --> must be 'word'
```

Right now my codes doesnt pull the word instead it pulls out the number. Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: `typeof el == 'string'`? `Array.prototype.filter()` returns all the elements in the array **that match the condition you give**. In your case, you're saying "I want to match all the elements whose `typeof` is equal to `number`", but what you want are elements that match the type `string`.

Comment: using array reduce may be a better solution - also, word would never be the answer, as you only look at elements that are NOT strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's walk through your code.

The first line of your `longestWord` function:

```
var filtered = arr.filter(function(el) { return typeof el == 'number' });
```

will filter the input array based on `typeof el === 'number'`, which will return an array containing only the elements of the input array which are `type of === number`.

Since the goal is to find the longest word, this should probably be changed to:

```
var filtered = arr.filter(function(el) { return typeof el === 'string' });
```

which will return an array of the strings in the input array.

Next, there's a check to see if the filtered array is empty. If the array is empty, you return `0`. Your instructions say that if the array is empty, or if the array contains no strings, it should return an empty string. So we should change this to:

```
return "";
```

If the array is not empty, or contains strings, `Math.min.apply(Math, filtered)` is returned. This statement would return the minimum value of an array, so probably not what you want. After all, the goal is to return the longest string.

To do this we can use a variety of methods, here's one:

```
filtered.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.length > b.length ? a : b })
```

This statement uses the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example) method to step through the array and return the longest item.

Putting it all together we get:

```js
function longestWord(arr) {
  var filtered = arr.filter(function(el) { return typeof el === 'string' });
  if (filtered.length > 0) {
    return filtered.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.length >= b.length ? a : b });
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}

console.log(longestWord([3, 'word', 5, 'up', 3, 'testing', 1]));
console.log(longestWord([]));
console.log(longestWord([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
console.log(longestWord(['some', 'long', 'four', 'char', 'strs']))
```

Comment: it must return the longest string in an array that appears first when there are ties

Comment: That's an easy, minor fix to the solution above. We've got you most of they way  there, and are here to help you learn, but not do your work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the filter meant to be for "string"

Once you have the filtered array, you can simply use reduce to get the longest word

```js
function longestWord(arr) {
    return Array.isArray(arr) ?
        arr
        .filter(el => typeof el == 'string' )
        .reduce((a,b) => b.length > a.length ? b : a) : '';
}
console.log(longestWord([3, 'word', 5, 'up', 3, 1, 'blah']));
```

> Even shorter code

```
var longestWord = (arr) => Array.isArray(arr) ? arr.reduce((a,b) => (typeof b == 'string' && b.length > a.length) ? b : a, '') : '';
```

Comment: it must return the longest string in an array that appears first when there are ties

Comment: This code does exactly that (with the edit) also, the "even shorter code" already did that :p

Answer (score 0):

```
const longestWord = arr =>
  arr.reduce((result, str) =>
    typeof str == 'string' && result.length < str.length
      ? str 
      : result, '')
```

Comment: it must return the longest string in an array that appears first when there are ties

Comment: @JamesHedegon fixed

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most efficient code.  For that, seek other answers, especially those that use `reduce`, however I do find it more readable and thus easier to maintain:

```js
function longestWord(arr) {
  var filtered = arr.filter(el => typeof el === 'string')
                    .sort((a,b) => a.length > b.length ? -1 : 1 );
  if (filtered.length)
    return filtered[0];
  return null;
}

var output = longestWord([3, 'word', 5, 'up', 3, 1]);
console.log(output); // --> must be 'word'
```

But what to do when two strings are the same length?

Comment: it must return the longest string in an array that appears first when there are ties

Answer (score 0):

As all other answers are using `filter()`, `reduce()` and all that new and fancy methods, I'm gonna answer with the do-it-yourself method (i.e. the old fashion way).

```
function longestWord(arr) {
    if ( ! ( typeof arr === 'array' ) ) {
        console.log("That's not an array!");
        return '';
    }

    var longest = ''; // By default, the longest word is the empty string

    // Linear search
    for ( var i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++ ) {
        var el = arr[i];
        if ( typeof el === 'string' && el.length > longest.length ) {
            // Words STRICTLY GREATER than the last found word.
            // This way, only the first word (if two lengths match) will be considered.
            longest = el;
        }
    }

    return longest;
}
```

I know, this is probably **NOT** what you want since you're already using `filtered()`, but it works.